# ElasticSearch High-Level REST Client 7.0.1: Method `AcknowledgedResponse.fromXContent` does not exist

Tags: elasticsearch

**I'm getting an error that says this method does not exist during runtime:**

```
org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.AcknowledgedResponse.fromXContent
```

**When I run this code:**

```
final var request = new DeleteIndexRequest(indexName);
return client.indices().delete(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

**The relevant Maven dependency:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**The relevant imports:**

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.delete.DeleteIndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.AcknowledgedResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.indices.CreateIndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.client.indices.CreateIndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.indices.GetIndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentType;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.search.sort.FieldSortBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortOrder;
```

**Full error:**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.delete(IndicesClient.java:97)

The following method did not exist:

    org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.AcknowledgedResponse.fromXContent(Lorg/elasticsearch/common/xcontent/XContentParser;)Lorg/elasticsearch/action/support/master/AcknowledgedResponse;

The method's class, org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.AcknowledgedResponse, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:~/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.4.3/elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar!/org/elasticsearch/action/support/master/AcknowledgedResponse.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:~/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.4.3/elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.AcknowledgedResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly including the latest version of the `elasticsearch` library fixed it:

**Added to `<dependencies>` in `pom.xml`:**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For some reason, the High-Level REST Client was using ElasticSearch library version 6 by default.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone get here while searching for answer why there is no RequestOption class on my classpath, ***adding*** this library helped me:

```
dependency("org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:7.15.2")
```